# Not able use properties of to react-images Lightbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, lightbox, react-image

Not able to access onOpen and onAfterOpen, onAfterClose properties.
also not able to find document for properties of Lightbox.

```js
<Lightbox
  id="restaurant_lightbox_popup"
  backdropClosesModal={true}
  images={
    this.state.viewMenu
      ? this.getRestaurantMenuPopup()
      : this.getRestaurantImagesPopup()
  }
  isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
  onClickPrev={() => {}}
  onClickNext={() => {}}
  onClose={() => {}}
  onAfterClose={() => console.log("onopen")}
  currentImage={this.state.currentImage}
  imageCountSeparator="/"
  className="test"
/>
```